# Computer Freeze during Game Update/Installation

Tags: hard-drive, freeze

I am currently having an extreme strange problem on my computer.
My Computer is having full freezes. So no freezes where I still can move the mouse, no freezes where everything is blocked. And when I listen to music or watch a film the sound just "beezes".

So first i tough that it must be the ram, I run a test and found something, for this reason I bough a new ram. New Ram, same problem.
But then I realised that the freeze is not random. I actually only accures when I try to install cs:go on my second hard disk (not an ssd).

So now I ask you the question, what is the problem? What can I do?

Comment: take a fan and clear all the dust from your computer case, then set some thermal monitoring to see if you CPU temperature spikes when you put in under a load.

Comment: Hi the problem was probably the HD. Whenever I installed something on that Drive it crashed. I did change it and now it works.. so yeah I'm happy ^^ but thanks for your help

Comment: Nice to know, you can try and run Spinrite on the drive and see if it can help you rescue the drive.